# ACE editor + requirejs + AMD jquery plugin: mode cannot be loaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, requirejs, ace-editor

I am using this version of ACE - git://github.com/ajaxorg/ace.git

And the this is I load it via requirejs,

```
require([
    // Load our app module and pass it to our definition function
    'jquery',
    'ext/ace-master/lib/ace/ace'
...
```

And how I evoke the editor,

```
var editor = ace.edit("ace-editor");
editor.setTheme("ext/ace-master/lib/ace/theme/eclipse");
editor.getSession().setMode("ext/ace-master/lib/ace/mode/xml");
```

But I always get this error message, and syntax highlighter is not highlighting any code in the form,

> ```
> Could not load worker
> ace.js (line 1)
> TypeError: this.$mode.createWorker is not a function
>
>
> ...ts","module","ace/lib/lang"],function(a,b,c){var d=a("../lib/lang"),e=function()...
>
>
> TypeError: a.getTokenizer is not a function
>
>
> ...ts","module","ace/lib/lang"],function(a,b,c){var d=a("../lib/lang"),e=function()...
> ```

Did anyone come across this problem and know how to fix it?

If I use this build version - https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/ there are even more errors - files not found, etc.

or this http://d1n0x3qji82z53.cloudfront.net/src-min-noconflict/ace.js - lots of not-found errors!

Note: I **load the form** via **jquery ajax**  by the way, is it the ajax that causing the error??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have miconfigured require paths

add

```
require.config({paths: {
    ace: "ext/ace-master/lib/ace"
}})
```

before the first require
and use `setMode("ace/mode/xml");`

see http://jsbin.com/ojijeb/339/edit for working version

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your AJAX is loading your form after the rest of the Javascript has already finished.

You can have the same function reload your Javascript but I'm not sure what kind of conflicts might arise since your code isn't really all here.

I had a similar issue and to overcome it I included the Javascript inside of the data that came through with the HTML I was requesting.  Food for thought.

Comment: thanks. how do you ` included the Javascript inside of the data`? could you please show some examples? Do you mean that placing the ACE inside the form itself?

Comment: Well I'm not sure what you're going for but in my case, I request parts of an HTML file with some `div`s and whatnot and at the end of the chunk of code I slapped my `<script src=...></script>`  If you wanna see it in action to see if it's related to your situation, i sandboxed it on my server at http://asims.fleeceitout.com

Comment: I know it's just the concept I wanted to demonstrate.  If you get stuck further down the line let me know and we'll try to work it out

Answer (score 0):

Got it worked with this build version - https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/ finally.